# Problems when modelling a Shape Memory Alloy (SMA) system

Tags: simulink

Current have been stuck trying to implement an agnostic SMA simulink simulation so I can develop a control for position. In trying to solve the problem I keep getting errors, large oscillations or large values outside what should be seen.

Any help or suggestions would be appreated as I have been stuck on this for quite a while. I've updated my two attempts to github (see below.

https://github.com/Jconnor20/Shape-Memory-Alloy-Controller

I've tried different phase models, I am pretty certain the heat model is correct and possibly the constitutive model. The problem may be in the kinetic or dynamic models however, I modelled a simple rotary system as shown in "Developing a fast response SMA-actuated rotary actuator:
modeling and experimental validation".
It could also be in the why the system is implemented or connected .